# Defining a Git process

Tags: git, continuous-integration, devops, git-flow, aws-codecommit

I am defining a CI/CD process with git and aws codeCommmit, here are the steps:

1. A release branch is created from master
2. Project branch is created from the release branch
3. Developers create as many feature branches from project branch
4. Instances of the feature branch is checked out to local.
5. Developer makes changes, checks into the feature branch.
6. Developers raises a pull request from the feature branch:
   (i) If there is a merge conflict, developer first merges project branch code to local, resolves the merge conflict and checks-in again in the already opened pull request of the feature branch.
   (ii) developer raises code review
   (iii). Automated checks like build syntax, static analysis, code coverages to check sanctity of the code goes here.
7. developer merges code back to the project branch.
8. CI build is triggered and deployed into develop environment and git tag id is generated.
9. On a given build date, developer notifies QE to get code from project branch to be deployed to QE environment.
   **(a) Alternatively, developer can give separate tag id which has to be deployed in QE environment.**
   10(a).when there is no separate UAT/Stage environment:

   - When all features are tested, project branch is merged to the release branch.
10. Release branch is deployed to production.
11. After successful production deployment, master is rebased with the release branch.

Will till process work seamlessly. 
At point 9(a), how can the git bookmark a specific dev build to be deployed in QA env ?